# Saving multiple frames from openCV with time as their name

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I'm trying to write a code that saves the some frames from openCV video Streaming. the name of the saved images should be the time : here is my code:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<conio.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

 int main(){

int key = 0;
char dateStr[9];
char timeStr[9];
_strdate(dateStr);
_strtime(timeStr);
char buffer[20];

 VideoCapture cap(1); // open the default camera
if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;


namedWindow("image",1);
while(key!=27)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    imshow("image", frame);

    if(key==13){
        sprintf(buffer,"%s%s.tif",dateStr,timeStr);
        imwrite(buffer,frame);

        }
    key = waitKey(1000); 
} 

destroyAllWindows();
// the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
return 0;

}
```

when I run this nothing happens and I hit the enter button more than once nothing happens   and by the way the streaming is too slow .  any Idea!! .
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

The streaming is slow because you are waiting too long.  Change the value in `key = waitKey(1000);` to change the frame rate of your program.

Also, if you ever hit enter, you will only save the *next* frame, not the frame you currently see.  You should move that `key = waitKey(1000);` statement to before the `if` statement.

Comment: thanks Chris that'S explain the speed of the video I had a problem with buffer, so I decieded to using a int i, to save multiple images with an index. here is my code

Comment: @Engine Looks good, you are having no more problems?  I'd still suggest moving the key = waitKey code to before the if statement.